# How to pass alert/console for each page in pagination to check weather it is passing to the particular page or not?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
<div class="gridview-plp" v-for="product in productsList" :key="product.key" id="product" :items="productsList" :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage">
  <div class="plp-list-img1desc">
    {{ product.key }}
  </div>

  <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" @page-click="handleClick(event, pageNumber)" :per-page="perPage"></b-pagination>
```

```html
currentPage: 1,
  perPage: 4,
  computed: {
    rows() {
      return this.productsList.length;
    },
    productsList() {
      return this.productsList.slice(
        this.currentPage * this.perPage,
        (this.currentPage + 1) * this.perPage
      );
    },
  },


  handleClick(event, pageNumber) {
    alert('hi');
  }
```

How to pass  different alert/console for each page, To check weather it is passing to the particular page or not?

Because i want to add specific event for each page,

Comment: using perPage or CurrentPage can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanna check user in which page? May be this helps you [Vue Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) or you can use this for getting page url.

```js
this.$route.path
```

Comment: Thanks, But where do i need to place that in my code, Because generally i am taking an event instead of that, how to place router for above code

Comment: are you not using vue router ? https://router.vuejs.org/installation.html#npm

Comment: No i am not using